# Connecting to MS SQL instance in Visual Studio Code using AD credentials over SSH Tunnel from Mac?

Tags: sql-server, macos, visual-studio, ssh, ssh-tunnel

At work, I have access to a database running on a Microsoft SQL sever that is part of our AD domain, using my AD credentials for logging in.  Access has been limited to the IP address assigned to my main work computer, which is a Mac running High Sierra.

To connect to the server/database, I've installed the mssql extension in Visual Studio Code, and I can connect with my AD credentials by following instructions listed in the Mac section of this page:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/wiki/How-to-enable-Integrated-Authentication-on-macOS-and-Linux-using-Kerberos

I'd also like to access this database from home (whether from my home Windows 10 machine, or from my work MacBook), so I worked on connecting to this server/database from VSCode on these machines, using a SSH port forward to tunnel all of the traffic through my work machine, which I can SSH into over the company VPN.

From my home Windows 10 machine, I'm able to connect to the server/database in the following way:

-configure the puTTY session for my home machine to add a SSH tunnel, with the source port 11433 and destination of [IP of MS SQL server]:1433

-go into the Credential Manager app on the Windows 10 machine, and add a Windows Credential that consists of 127.0.0.1:11433 as the Network address, and my AD credentials under User name/Password.

-configure an MS SQL Connection in Visual Studio Code that points to 127.0.0.1,11433, and uses the Integration Connection type.

I would like to do something similar on my MacBook, but I'm having issues with getting this configured in Visual Studio code.  I did some other testing by installing the freetds package from Homebrew on the MacBook, and I can connect to the server/database over the SSH tunnel set up in ~/.ssh/config, so I know I have the port forward info set correctly within the SSH config.

Has anyone out there been able to configure access from VSCode on Mac OS over a SSH tunnel so it will pass the AD credentials?

Thanks in advance, and if you need any further details, please let me know.

Paul